# Redux-form-material-ui - Can't resolve 'material-ui/Radio'

Tags: material-ui, redux-form

I have migrated to the upcoming version (v1) of material-UI, and I installed v1 alongside the current version according to the recommendation:

```
yarn add material-ui@latest
yarn add material-ui-next@npm:material-ui@next
```

When I try to use redux-form and use the package **redux-form-material-ui** to connect the components, it searches for the material-UI components in "material-ui" folder, which gives an error:

```
Error: Can't resolve 'material-ui/Radio' in 'C:\path\to\redux-form-material-ui\lib'
```

But I import Radio from `material-ui-next/Radio`
So it looks for it in the wrong version.

How can I make this work? Should I uninstall the current version and install "next" as "material-ui" instead?

Here is what is installed:

```
"material-ui": "^0.20.0",
"material-ui-next": "npm:material-ui@next",
"redux-form-material-ui": "^5.0.0-beta.2",
"redux-form": "^7.3.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

My way of getting around the problem was to uninstall both material UI packages and then install the v1 as "material-ui" , and the old one as "material-ui-old":

```
"material-ui": "npm:material-ui@next", 
"material-ui-old": "npm:material-ui"
```

I had to change all the imports in the project.
But now it finds the 'material-ui/Radio'.